# Is Flyway ever aware of the db state or it validates exclusively immutability of migration files?

Tags: java, database, flyway

I have difficulties finding concrete info on how Flyway works when validating. Is checksum applied over the migaration as a file or over the migration as actual db changes? Does it just compare content of migration files when applied over the db versus current content or is it someway aware of the information schema of db with its current state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flyway maintains a special table in the schema.

This table contains an information about all DB migrations that have been applied so far.

When it runs, flyway checks whether the codebase has new migration(s) compared to already applied from that table, if there are new migrations it applies them one by one, otherwise just finishes.

So, the source of knowledge for flyway is the schema that has flyway's own table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am not sure you answered exactly my point though, except for the last line. Does that mean that Flyway takes a snapshot of the db information_schema in some way? Or does the checksum apply only over the migration file?

Comment: checksum is something that makes sure that migration file itself is not changed compared to the "version" of the same migration file that was used when the actual migration happened. Flyway doesn't make any snpshots of the db information schema. It works only with its own table in schema and a list of locally available files - migrations.

Comment: Then Flyway does not validates immutability of the db, it just validates immutability of the migration files content, cool